# Как создать график курса валюты

Tags: json, api, диаграммы, highcharts

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу создать график (который автоматически обновляется) курса криптовалюты? Потратил очень много времени уже на это, (новичок), узнал что это можно реализовать с помощью google charts. Есть json файл, на основе которого нужно сделать линейный график как на этой странице: https://blockchain.info/ru/charts/market-price

Вот сам файл json: https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json

Использую такой код:

```
<html>

<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
      }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new
      google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {
        width: 400,
        height: 240
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

В файле getData.php следующее содержание

```
// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the 
client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

$string = 
file_get_contents("https://api.blockchain.info/charts/transactions-per-
second?timespan=5weeks&rollingAverage=8hours&format=json");
echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

?>
```

когда захожу на страницу появляется такая ошибка: Table has no columns.

Comment: https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html попробуйте эту библиотеку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так у меня собрался график

```js
$(function(){
//  $.ajax({
//   type: 'GET',
//    dataType: 'json',
//    url: 'market-price.json'
//  }).done(function(data){
//    renderChart(data);
//  });
  
  var data = {
  "status": "ok",
  "name": "Market Price (USD)",
  "unit": "USD",
  "period": "day",
  "description": "Average USD market price across major bitcoin exchanges.",
  "values": [
    {
      "x": 1466640000,
      "y": 624.54
    },
    {
      "x": 1466726400,
      "y": 660.60
    },
    {
      "x": 1466812800,
      "y": 664.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1466899200,
      "y": 627.39
    },
    {
      "x": 1466985600,
      "y": 646.70
    },
    {
      "x": 1467072000,
      "y": 646.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1467158400,
      "y": 637.95
    },
    {
      "x": 1467244800,
      "y": 671.40
    },
    {
      "x": 1467331200,
      "y": 675.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1467417600,
      "y": 701.71
    },
    {
      "x": 1467504000,
      "y": 658.41
    },
    {
      "x": 1467590400,
      "y": 676.32
    },
    {
      "x": 1467676800,
      "y": 666.48
    },
    {
      "x": 1467763200,
      "y": 673.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1467849600,
      "y": 636.35
    },
    {
      "x": 1467936000,
      "y": 659.55
    },
    {
      "x": 1468022400,
      "y": 651.86
    },
    {
      "x": 1468108800,
      "y": 648.09
    },
    {
      "x": 1468195200,
      "y": 647.98
    },
    {
      "x": 1468281600,
      "y": 672.76
    },
    {
      "x": 1468368000,
      "y": 657.45
    },
    {
      "x": 1468454400,
      "y": 658.83
    },
    {
      "x": 1468540800,
      "y": 664.57
    },
    {
      "x": 1468627200,
      "y": 662.15
    },
    {
      "x": 1468713600,
      "y": 675.45
    },
    {
      "x": 1468800000,
      "y": 673.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1468886400,
      "y": 672.84
    },
    {
      "x": 1468972800,
      "y": 665.64
    },
    {
      "x": 1469059200,
      "y": 664.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1469145600,
      "y": 651.58
    },
    {
      "x": 1469232000,
      "y": 655.84
    },
    {
      "x": 1469318400,
      "y": 661.41
    },
    {
      "x": 1469404800,
      "y": 654.69
    },
    {
      "x": 1469491200,
      "y": 655.06
    },
    {
      "x": 1469577600,
      "y": 654.98
    },
    {
      "x": 1469664000,
      "y": 655.32
    },
    {
      "x": 1469750400,
      "y": 656.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1469836800,
      "y": 654.73
    },
    {
      "x": 1469923200,
      "y": 628.01
    },
    {
      "x": 1470009600,
      "y": 606.32
    },
    {
      "x": 1470096000,
      "y": 515.06
    },
    {
      "x": 1470182400,
      "y": 565.05
    },
    {
      "x": 1470268800,
      "y": 577.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1470355200,
      "y": 576.55
    },
    {
      "x": 1470441600,
      "y": 588.23
    },
    {
      "x": 1470528000,
      "y": 594.27
    },
    {
      "x": 1470614400,
      "y": 592.69
    },
    {
      "x": 1470700800,
      "y": 588.77
    },
    {
      "x": 1470787200,
      "y": 592.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1470873600,
      "y": 589.24
    },
    {
      "x": 1470960000,
      "y": 587.75
    },
    {
      "x": 1471046400,
      "y": 586.43
    },
    {
      "x": 1471132800,
      "y": 570.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1471219200,
      "y": 570.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1471305600,
      "y": 581.11
    },
    {
      "x": 1471392000,
      "y": 575.51
    },
    {
      "x": 1471478400,
      "y": 576.03
    },
    {
      "x": 1471564800,
      "y": 576.65
    },
    {
      "x": 1471651200,
      "y": 583.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1471737600,
      "y": 582.82
    },
    {
      "x": 1471824000,
      "y": 588.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1471910400,
      "y": 586.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1471996800,
      "y": 582.84
    },
    {
      "x": 1472083200,
      "y": 579.86
    },
    {
      "x": 1472169600,
      "y": 581.07
    },
    {
      "x": 1472256000,
      "y": 571.54
    },
    {
      "x": 1472342400,
      "y": 576.53
    },
    {
      "x": 1472428800,
      "y": 575.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1472515200,
      "y": 578.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1472601600,
      "y": 574.82
    },
    {
      "x": 1472688000,
      "y": 572.81
    },
    {
      "x": 1472774400,
      "y": 576.21
    },
    {
      "x": 1472860800,
      "y": 600.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1472947200,
      "y": 610.59
    },
    {
      "x": 1473033600,
      "y": 608.10
    },
    {
      "x": 1473120000,
      "y": 611.09
    },
    {
      "x": 1473206400,
      "y": 614.46
    },
    {
      "x": 1473292800,
      "y": 627.77
    },
    {
      "x": 1473379200,
      "y": 625.07
    },
    {
      "x": 1473465600,
      "y": 625.76
    },
    {
      "x": 1473552000,
      "y": 608.15
    },
    {
      "x": 1473638400,
      "y": 609.67
    },
    {
      "x": 1473724800,
      "y": 610.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1473811200,
      "y": 612.08
    },
    {
      "x": 1473897600,
      "y": 610.38
    },
    {
      "x": 1473984000,
      "y": 609.11
    },
    {
      "x": 1474070400,
      "y": 608.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1474156800,
      "y": 611.58
    },
    {
      "x": 1474243200,
      "y": 610.19
    },
    {
      "x": 1474329600,
      "y": 609.74
    },
    {
      "x": 1474416000,
      "y": 598.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1474502400,
      "y": 597.42
    },
    {
      "x": 1474588800,
      "y": 604.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1474675200,
      "y": 603.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1474761600,
      "y": 601.74
    },
    {
      "x": 1474848000,
      "y": 608.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1474934400,
      "y": 605.96
    },
    {
      "x": 1475020800,
      "y": 605.67
    },
    {
      "x": 1475107200,
      "y": 606.36
    },
    {
      "x": 1475193600,
      "y": 609.39
    },
    {
      "x": 1475280000,
      "y": 614.82
    },
    {
      "x": 1475366400,
      "y": 610.51
    },
    {
      "x": 1475452800,
      "y": 611.85
    },
    {
      "x": 1475539200,
      "y": 609.62
    },
    {
      "x": 1475625600,
      "y": 612.35
    },
    {
      "x": 1475712000,
      "y": 612.08
    },
    {
      "x": 1475798400,
      "y": 617.21
    },
    {
      "x": 1475884800,
      "y": 618.04
    },
    {
      "x": 1475971200,
      "y": 615.65
    },
    {
      "x": 1476057600,
      "y": 617.54
    },
    {
      "x": 1476144000,
      "y": 639.30
    },
    {
      "x": 1476230400,
      "y": 635.01
    },
    {
      "x": 1476316800,
      "y": 635.96
    },
    {
      "x": 1476403200,
      "y": 639.56
    },
    {
      "x": 1476489600,
      "y": 637.94
    },
    {
      "x": 1476576000,
      "y": 641.42
    },
    {
      "x": 1476662400,
      "y": 638.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1476748800,
      "y": 636.29
    },
    {
      "x": 1476835200,
      "y": 629.25
    },
    {
      "x": 1476921600,
      "y": 630.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1477008000,
      "y": 631.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1477094400,
      "y": 655.48
    },
    {
      "x": 1477180800,
      "y": 653.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1477267200,
      "y": 651.39
    },
    {
      "x": 1477353600,
      "y": 655.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1477440000,
      "y": 672.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1477526400,
      "y": 682.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1477612800,
      "y": 687.68
    },
    {
      "x": 1477699200,
      "y": 714.89
    },
    {
      "x": 1477785600,
      "y": 698.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1477872000,
      "y": 702.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1477958400,
      "y": 728.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1478044800,
      "y": 733.33
    },
    {
      "x": 1478131200,
      "y": 686.17
    },
    {
      "x": 1478217600,
      "y": 703.69
    },
    {
      "x": 1478304000,
      "y": 704.79
    },
    {
      "x": 1478390400,
      "y": 712.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1478476800,
      "y": 703.81
    },
    {
      "x": 1478563200,
      "y": 708.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1478649600,
      "y": 720.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1478736000,
      "y": 713.69
    },
    {
      "x": 1478822400,
      "y": 715.45
    },
    {
      "x": 1478908800,
      "y": 703.71
    },
    {
      "x": 1478995200,
      "y": 701.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1479081600,
      "y": 706.46
    },
    {
      "x": 1479168000,
      "y": 710.91
    },
    {
      "x": 1479254400,
      "y": 736.91
    },
    {
      "x": 1479340800,
      "y": 736.96
    },
    {
      "x": 1479427200,
      "y": 747.52
    },
    {
      "x": 1479513600,
      "y": 750.03
    },
    {
      "x": 1479600000,
      "y": 729.06
    },
    {
      "x": 1479686400,
      "y": 738.53
    },
    {
      "x": 1479772800,
      "y": 748.74
    },
    {
      "x": 1479859200,
      "y": 741.63
    },
    {
      "x": 1479945600,
      "y": 737.45
    },
    {
      "x": 1480032000,
      "y": 739.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1480118400,
      "y": 733.67
    },
    {
      "x": 1480204800,
      "y": 727.96
    },
    {
      "x": 1480291200,
      "y": 733.05
    },
    {
      "x": 1480377600,
      "y": 732.71
    },
    {
      "x": 1480464000,
      "y": 742.69
    },
    {
      "x": 1480550400,
      "y": 752.24
    },
    {
      "x": 1480636800,
      "y": 772.43
    },
    {
      "x": 1480723200,
      "y": 764.33
    },
    {
      "x": 1480809600,
      "y": 764.81
    },
    {
      "x": 1480896000,
      "y": 754.63
    },
    {
      "x": 1480982400,
      "y": 756.62
    },
    {
      "x": 1481068800,
      "y": 766.11
    },
    {
      "x": 1481155200,
      "y": 769.72
    },
    {
      "x": 1481241600,
      "y": 770.02
    },
    {
      "x": 1481328000,
      "y": 773.40
    },
    {
      "x": 1481414400,
      "y": 768.30
    },
    {
      "x": 1481500800,
      "y": 777.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1481587200,
      "y": 778.49
    },
    {
      "x": 1481673600,
      "y": 774.89
    },
    {
      "x": 1481760000,
      "y": 776.75
    },
    {
      "x": 1481846400,
      "y": 781.56
    },
    {
      "x": 1481932800,
      "y": 788.70
    },
    {
      "x": 1482019200,
      "y": 788.40
    },
    {
      "x": 1482105600,
      "y": 789.52
    },
    {
      "x": 1482192000,
      "y": 793.09
    },
    {
      "x": 1482278400,
      "y": 824.21
    },
    {
      "x": 1482364800,
      "y": 860.59
    },
    {
      "x": 1482451200,
      "y": 901.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1482537600,
      "y": 891.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1482624000,
      "y": 886.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1482710400,
      "y": 897.33
    },
    {
      "x": 1482796800,
      "y": 930.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1482883200,
      "y": 967.48
    },
    {
      "x": 1482969600,
      "y": 963.38
    },
    {
      "x": 1483056000,
      "y": 952.15
    },
    {
      "x": 1483142400,
      "y": 959.87
    },
    {
      "x": 1483228800,
      "y": 997.72
    },
    {
      "x": 1483315200,
      "y": 1015.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1483401600,
      "y": 1023.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1483488000,
      "y": 1126.76
    },
    {
      "x": 1483574400,
      "y": 994.67
    },
    {
      "x": 1483660800,
      "y": 883.09
    },
    {
      "x": 1483747200,
      "y": 896.83
    },
    {
      "x": 1483833600,
      "y": 908.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1483920000,
      "y": 894.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1484006400,
      "y": 906.05
    },
    {
      "x": 1484092800,
      "y": 785.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1484179200,
      "y": 803.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1484265600,
      "y": 826.29
    },
    {
      "x": 1484352000,
      "y": 817.91
    },
    {
      "x": 1484438400,
      "y": 822.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1484524800,
      "y": 830.50
    },
    {
      "x": 1484611200,
      "y": 903.84
    },
    {
      "x": 1484697600,
      "y": 874.99
    },
    {
      "x": 1484784000,
      "y": 895.79
    },
    {
      "x": 1484870400,
      "y": 893.62
    },
    {
      "x": 1484956800,
      "y": 920.44
    },
    {
      "x": 1485043200,
      "y": 918.60
    },
    {
      "x": 1485129600,
      "y": 922.07
    },
    {
      "x": 1485216000,
      "y": 890.32
    },
    {
      "x": 1485302400,
      "y": 893.04
    },
    {
      "x": 1485388800,
      "y": 915.95
    },
    {
      "x": 1485475200,
      "y": 919.27
    },
    {
      "x": 1485561600,
      "y": 920.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1485648000,
      "y": 915.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1485734400,
      "y": 921.17
    },
    {
      "x": 1485820800,
      "y": 964.70
    },
    {
      "x": 1485907200,
      "y": 979.70
    },
    {
      "x": 1485993600,
      "y": 1007.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1486080000,
      "y": 1013.02
    },
    {
      "x": 1486166400,
      "y": 1030.99
    },
    {
      "x": 1486252800,
      "y": 1014.83
    },
    {
      "x": 1486339200,
      "y": 1024.01
    },
    {
      "x": 1486425600,
      "y": 1050.11
    },
    {
      "x": 1486512000,
      "y": 1052.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1486598400,
      "y": 976.10
    },
    {
      "x": 1486684800,
      "y": 999.10
    },
    {
      "x": 1486771200,
      "y": 1008.84
    },
    {
      "x": 1486857600,
      "y": 1000.60
    },
    {
      "x": 1486944000,
      "y": 999.87
    },
    {
      "x": 1487030400,
      "y": 1011.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1487116800,
      "y": 1012.32
    },
    {
      "x": 1487203200,
      "y": 1035.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1487289600,
      "y": 1055.53
    },
    {
      "x": 1487376000,
      "y": 1056.63
    },
    {
      "x": 1487462400,
      "y": 1052.77
    },
    {
      "x": 1487548800,
      "y": 1084.75
    },
    {
      "x": 1487635200,
      "y": 1123.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1487721600,
      "y": 1123.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1487808000,
      "y": 1172.01
    },
    {
      "x": 1487894400,
      "y": 1174.86
    },
    {
      "x": 1487980800,
      "y": 1150.60
    },
    {
      "x": 1488067200,
      "y": 1175.04
    },
    {
      "x": 1488153600,
      "y": 1190.75
    },
    {
      "x": 1488240000,
      "y": 1187.56
    },
    {
      "x": 1488326400,
      "y": 1222.49
    },
    {
      "x": 1488412800,
      "y": 1259.41
    },
    {
      "x": 1488499200,
      "y": 1285.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1488585600,
      "y": 1267.02
    },
    {
      "x": 1488672000,
      "y": 1270.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1488758400,
      "y": 1275.19
    },
    {
      "x": 1488844800,
      "y": 1238.44
    },
    {
      "x": 1488931200,
      "y": 1157.39
    },
    {
      "x": 1489017600,
      "y": 1192.46
    },
    {
      "x": 1489104000,
      "y": 1098.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1489190400,
      "y": 1179.15
    },
    {
      "x": 1489276800,
      "y": 1227.49
    },
    {
      "x": 1489363200,
      "y": 1239.81
    },
    {
      "x": 1489449600,
      "y": 1245.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1489536000,
      "y": 1257.39
    },
    {
      "x": 1489622400,
      "y": 1180.94
    },
    {
      "x": 1489708800,
      "y": 1091.17
    },
    {
      "x": 1489795200,
      "y": 952.23
    },
    {
      "x": 1489881600,
      "y": 1029.80
    },
    {
      "x": 1489968000,
      "y": 1049.08
    },
    {
      "x": 1490054400,
      "y": 1118.63
    },
    {
      "x": 1490140800,
      "y": 1028.72
    },
    {
      "x": 1490227200,
      "y": 1038.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1490313600,
      "y": 941.91
    },
    {
      "x": 1490400000,
      "y": 959.34
    },
    {
      "x": 1490486400,
      "y": 956.78
    },
    {
      "x": 1490572800,
      "y": 1037.22
    },
    {
      "x": 1490659200,
      "y": 1046.12
    },
    {
      "x": 1490745600,
      "y": 1040.57
    },
    {
      "x": 1490832000,
      "y": 1037.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1490918400,
      "y": 1079.54
    },
    {
      "x": 1491004800,
      "y": 1086.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1491091200,
      "y": 1099.16
    },
    {
      "x": 1491177600,
      "y": 1141.81
    },
    {
      "x": 1491264000,
      "y": 1141.60
    },
    {
      "x": 1491350400,
      "y": 1133.07
    },
    {
      "x": 1491436800,
      "y": 1196.30
    },
    {
      "x": 1491523200,
      "y": 1190.45
    },
    {
      "x": 1491609600,
      "y": 1181.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1491696000,
      "y": 1208.80
    },
    {
      "x": 1491782400,
      "y": 1207.74
    },
    {
      "x": 1491868800,
      "y": 1226.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1491955200,
      "y": 1218.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1492041600,
      "y": 1180.02
    },
    {
      "x": 1492128000,
      "y": 1185.26
    },
    {
      "x": 1492214400,
      "y": 1184.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1492300800,
      "y": 1186.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1492387200,
      "y": 1205.63
    },
    {
      "x": 1492473600,
      "y": 1216.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1492560000,
      "y": 1217.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1492646400,
      "y": 1241.68
    },
    {
      "x": 1492732800,
      "y": 1258.36
    },
    {
      "x": 1492819200,
      "y": 1261.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1492905600,
      "y": 1257.98
    },
    {
      "x": 1492992000,
      "y": 1262.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1493078400,
      "y": 1279.41
    },
    {
      "x": 1493164800,
      "y": 1309.10
    },
    {
      "x": 1493251200,
      "y": 1345.35
    },
    {
      "x": 1493337600,
      "y": 1331.29
    },
    {
      "x": 1493424000,
      "y": 1334.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1493510400,
      "y": 1353.00
    },
    {
      "x": 1493596800,
      "y": 1417.17
    },
    {
      "x": 1493683200,
      "y": 1452.07
    },
    {
      "x": 1493769600,
      "y": 1507.57
    },
    {
      "x": 1493856000,
      "y": 1508.29
    },
    {
      "x": 1493942400,
      "y": 1533.33
    },
    {
      "x": 1494028800,
      "y": 1560.41
    },
    {
      "x": 1494115200,
      "y": 1535.86
    },
    {
      "x": 1494201600,
      "y": 1640.61
    },
    {
      "x": 1494288000,
      "y": 1721.28
    },
    {
      "x": 1494374400,
      "y": 1762.88
    },
    {
      "x": 1494460800,
      "y": 1820.99
    },
    {
      "x": 1494547200,
      "y": 1720.47
    },
    {
      "x": 1494633600,
      "y": 1771.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1494720000,
      "y": 1776.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1494806400,
      "y": 1723.12
    },
    {
      "x": 1494892800,
      "y": 1739.03
    },
    {
      "x": 1494979200,
      "y": 1807.48
    },
    {
      "x": 1495065600,
      "y": 1899.08
    },
    {
      "x": 1495152000,
      "y": 1961.52
    },
    {
      "x": 1495238400,
      "y": 2052.90
    },
    {
      "x": 1495324800,
      "y": 2046.53
    },
    {
      "x": 1495411200,
      "y": 2090.66
    },
    {
      "x": 1495497600,
      "y": 2287.71
    },
    {
      "x": 1495584000,
      "y": 2379.19
    },
    {
      "x": 1495670400,
      "y": 2387.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1495756800,
      "y": 2211.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1495843200,
      "y": 2014.05
    },
    {
      "x": 1495929600,
      "y": 2192.98
    },
    {
      "x": 1496016000,
      "y": 2275.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1496102400,
      "y": 2239.20
    },
    {
      "x": 1496188800,
      "y": 2285.93
    },
    {
      "x": 1496275200,
      "y": 2399.24
    },
    {
      "x": 1496361600,
      "y": 2446.14
    },
    {
      "x": 1496448000,
      "y": 2525.76
    },
    {
      "x": 1496534400,
      "y": 2516.17
    },
    {
      "x": 1496620800,
      "y": 2698.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1496707200,
      "y": 2883.31
    },
    {
      "x": 1496793600,
      "y": 2664.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1496880000,
      "y": 2792.99
    },
    {
      "x": 1496966400,
      "y": 2827.49
    },
    {
      "x": 1497052800,
      "y": 2845.37
    },
    {
      "x": 1497139200,
      "y": 2961.82
    },
    {
      "x": 1497225600,
      "y": 2657.67
    },
    {
      "x": 1497312000,
      "y": 2748.18
    },
    {
      "x": 1497398400,
      "y": 2447.04
    },
    {
      "x": 1497484800,
      "y": 2442.48
    },
    {
      "x": 1497571200,
      "y": 2464.95
    },
    {
      "x": 1497657600,
      "y": 2665.92
    },
    {
      "x": 1497744000,
      "y": 2507.38
    },
    {
      "x": 1497830400,
      "y": 2617.21
    },
    {
      "x": 1497916800,
      "y": 2754.97
    },
    {
      "x": 1498003200,
      "y": 2671.04
    },
    {
      "x": 1498089600,
      "y": 2727.28
    }
  ]
};
renderChart(data);
});

function renderChart(data) {
  var courses = data && data.values || [];
  new Morris.Line({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: courses,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y'],
    labels: ['USD']
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы график содержал постоянно новые данные... То, что Вы предлагаете, насколько я понимаю статичная информация.

Comment: Ну так ходите через сокеты за данными

Comment: Если немного подробнее расскажете, буду очень признателен вам :) Дело в том, что я в первые слышу это слово (сокеты) )))

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js">
</script>

<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
//  $.ajax({
//   type: 'GET',
//    dataType: 'json',
//    url: 'market-price.json'
//  }).done(function(data){
//    renderChart(data);
//  });

  var data = {
  "status": "ok",
  "name": "Market Price (USD)",
  "unit": "USD",
  "period": "day",
  "description": "Average USD market price across major bitcoin exchanges.",
  "values": [
    {
      "x": 1466640000,
      "y": 624.54
    },
    {
      "x": 1466726400,
      "y": 660.60
    },
    {
  "x": 1466812800,
  "y": 664.90
},
{
  "x": 1466899200,
  "y": 627.39
},
{
  "x": 1466985600,
  "y": 646.70
},
{
  "x": 1467072000,
  "y": 646.37
    }
  ]
};
renderChart(data);
});

function renderChart(data) {
  var courses = data && data.values || [];
  new Morris.Line({
element: 'myfirstchart',
data: courses,
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y'],
labels: ['USD']
  });


</script>
```

Использую этот код, но открывается пустое окно...